# << notation on measures

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, metric-spaces, notation, signed-measures

If $\nu$ and $\mu$ are two signed measures of finite variation, what does the notation $\nu << \mu$ means?

Comment: It probably means that $\nu(E) = 0$ whenever $\mu(E) = 0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\mu$ is positive, then we write that $ \nu \ll \mu $ iff $\mu(S)=0\implies\nu(S)=0$ for every measurable set $S$. We say that $\nu$ is *absolutely continuous* with respect to $\mu.$

If $\mu$ is signed, then we replace $\mu$ by $|\mu|$ in the above.

Comment: Do we use the same definition when $\mu,\nu$ are positive measures and when either or both of them are signed measures? Don't we unnecessarily reject an otherwise perfectly fine case when $|\nu|\ll |\mu|$, but $\nu\not \ll \mu$, because $\exists S=S_1 \sqcup S_2$, s.t. $\mu(S_1) = -\mu(S_2) \neq 0$ and $\nu(S_1) \neq -\nu(S_2) \neq 0$?

Comment: Relevant Links: [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org//wiki/Absolute_continuity#Absolute_continuity_of_measures) and [Encyclopedia of Math entry](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Absolutely_continuous_measures)

Comment: Then it must be state explicitly that this accepted **answer is wrong** when $\mu$ in $\nu\ll\mu$ is a signed measure. See the second link in Calvin Khor's comment.

Comment: @paperskilltrees good point, fixed